pre-1972 novel where scientist puts his own brain in robot body and becomes immortal
It was a pre-1972 paperback novel. Bad guys were after a scientist's robot invention that ran on cosmic energy - they killed his family - he transferred his brain into the robot. He had a lot of adventures, buried for thousands (or millions?) of years, traveled with aliens, became the oldest living being in the universe, etc.

This sounds a lot like the Professor Jameson Space Adventure Series by Neil R. Jones. Definitely pre-1972!

@MarkOlson Yep, Prof. Jameson lived a long time, traveled with aliens, and had lots of adventures, but his origin story was completely different: no bad guys killing his family, he didn't invent any robots or transfer his own brain into a mechanical body.

I wonder if this is a conflation of the Captain Future stories with the Professor Jameson stories. CBruce, in the Captain Future stories the bad guy is Corvo. Does that ring any bells?

I'm familiar with the Captain Future series. Professor Jameson series, etc... not related. This was a standalone novel and the "bad guys" were just thugs at the very beginning that killed his family.
